# how to convert a stored erlang term to a string outside of erlang

Tags: erlang, riak

I have stored an **Erlang** Term into a bucket/key in **Riak**.

**This Term is stored as what I believe is binary by Erlang**.

For example this is the original erlang Term: {someAtom,[1,2,3],{"text1","text2"}}

Using a **java** program I am trying to obtain the data using a riak client, but the data is encoded. Riak stores data as binary as well, but the java client has a getValueAsString() method, but that does not work (obviously) since the source data was binary.

The point is, if I read this data as byte[] in java, how do I decode it to a string that reppresents this text : {someAtom,[1,2,3],{"text1","text2"}} ? To be more specific, is erlang storing as bytes that reppresent individual character's ASCII code ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure you use wrong interface to access data from Java. Take a look at [Riak Java client quick start](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client#quick-start). They don't use `getValueAsString()` and there is a code where they use `RiakResponse.getRiakObjects()`. Try it.